# Share canvas on Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, canvas

I have a site where the user can design smartphone cases. At one point the user should be able to share the design on Facebook, including the design. I have the  object as well as a , with the 'style' set as the data URI of the canvas.

The code for custom image while sharing is:

How would I go to share it with my image, as it's a data URI.

Thanks

**UPDATE**:
I now have the canvas saved down on the server, linked correctly. Although, I can't seem to be able to edit the "href" of the link Facebook read the thumbnail picture from.

I tried:

var fblink = document.getElementById("facebook_share");
fblink.href="http://example.com/image.png";

AND

fblink.setAttribute("href", "http://example.com/image.png");

None seem to work. The 'fblink' object is correct as I can read the 'rel' etc.

Comment: Is saving the canvas data to your server as an image (and using the URL of that) not an option?

Comment: I'm actually looking as we're speaking on how to do that. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried this approach: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/ (the biggest issue you're likely to face is cross-server security - you need to make sure you're saving the image on the same machine that serves your Canvas and javascript)

Comment: That's basically doing the same thing as I have, difference is the 'src' is the data URI holder and not the 'style' as in my case.

Comment: What server-side technology are you using (ASP.NET, PHP etc.)? This sin't something that can be achieved just by using front-end code AFAIK.

Comment: See the first question, it's updated.

Answer (score 1):

I personally used `canvas.toDataURL()` which generates a base64 encoded URL of your canvas content.

After that I decoded the URL using the following command `Base64Binary.decode(encodedPng)`

Once you have your decoded image you can put it in a form and send all that through an XMLHttpRequest object as specified in the code below:

```
            // Random boundary defined to separate element in form
            var boundary = '----ThisIsTheBoundary1234567890';

            // this is the multipart/form-data boundary we'll use
            var formData = '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
            formData += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"; filename="' + filename + '"\r\n';
            formData += 'Content-Type: ' + mimeType + '\r\n\r\n';

            // let's encode our image file
            for ( var i = 0; i < imageData.length; ++i ) {
                formData += String.fromCharCode( imageData[ i ] & 0xff );
            }

            formData += '\r\n';
            formData += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
            formData += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n';
            formData += message + '\r\n'
            formData += '--' + boundary + '--\r\n';

            // Create a POST XML Http Request
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open( 'POST', 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=' + authToken, true );
            // Call back function if POST request succeed or fail
            xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function() {
                if ( !(xhr.responseText.split('"')[1] == "error") ) {
                    // If there is no error we redirect the user to the FB post she/he just created
                    var userID = xhr.responseText.split('"')[7].split('_')[0];
                    var postID = xhr.responseText.split('"')[7].split('_')[1];
                    w = window.open('https://www.facebook.com/'+userID+'/posts/'+postID,
                            'width=1235,height=530');
                }
                else {
                    alert("Erreur: "+xhr.responseText);
                }
            };
            xhr.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary );

            // Attach the data to the request as binary
            xhr.sendAsBinary( formData );
```

You can see a full working example on my [Github project](https://github.com/gregriggins36/showcase-try-on) in the file maskToFb.html